# regular expression for regex shell: escaping \

Tags: regex

can anyone help me with creating regex for escapging?

example1) 
`shell> echo lll\< kkkk\\\ uuuu\&`

needs to print
*lll< kkkk\ uuuu&*

---

example2) 
`shell> echo \"Hello hello1 hello2"\`

*"Hello hello1 hello2"*

---

excample3)
`shell> echo this is a question mark \?`

*this is a question mark*

Comment: These examples make no sense. The first example suggests backslash escapes the next character. The second example suggests backslash escapes maybe the next, maybe the previous character. The third example suggest backslash removes the next character.

Comment: I've reformated my questions. sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.+echo\s|([\\?])\1+|[\\?]`

just you need replace this with `$1`

- '.+echo\s' - With this you remove echo and all words before it
- '([\?])\1+' - get any `\` or `?` that is duplicate and replace with
  one character by `$1`
- '[\?]' - and remove any `\` and `?` that is one

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/yv8RLf/3/)

Comment: Thanks to you I found out about the regular expression101 site which is awesome :-)